qml.device error
I am having an error when calling the device:
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np

# Number of qubits (8 in total: 4 for nuclear spins, 4 for electronic states)
n_wires = 8

# Define initial random parameters for the circuit.
np.random.seed(42)
params = np.random.normal(0, np.pi, 3*n_wires)

# Hyperfine interaction strength
lambda_hyperfine = 1.0  # Moderate hyperfine coupling strength

# Magnetic field vector (for Zeeman splitting)
B_field = np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.1])  # Moderate magnetic field strength

# Define TN method
kwargs_tn = {
    "contract": False,
    "local_simplify": "DCRS",
    "contraction_optimizer": None,
}
 

# Define a device to simulate our quantum system with 8 qubits
dev = qml.device("default.tensor", method="tn", **kwargs_tn) 

# Quantum circuit to model nuclear-electronic entanglement with hyperfine and magnetic field effects
@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit_with_energy(params):
    """
    Quantum circuit that simulates the nuclear-electronic interaction and entanglement in a topological superconductor.
    It includes the hyperfine interaction between nuclear and electronic spins and an external magnetic field.
    
    Args:
        params (array): Array of parameters for the rotation gates.
        
    Returns:
        tuple: The full quantum state vector.
    """

    qml.Hadamard(wires=0)
    for i in range(1, n_wires):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[0, i])

    # Apply single-qubit rotation gates to simulate spin-orbit coupling and nuclear dynamics.
    for i in range(n_wires):
        qml.RX(params[i], wires=i)  # Rotate around the X-axis
        qml.RY(params[i + n_wires], wires=i)  # Rotate around the Y-axis
        qml.RZ(params[i + 2*n_wires], wires=i)  # Rotate around the Z-axis
    
    # Entangle the nuclear and electronic qubits using CNOT gates (4 nuclear-electronic pairs).
    for i in range(0, n_wires, 2):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[i, i+1])  # Entangle nuclear qubit i and electronic qubit i+1
    
    # Apply additional rotations for the hyperfine interaction (between nuclear and electronic qubits).
    for i in range(0, n_wires, 2):
        qml.RX(lambda_hyperfine * params[i], wires=i)  # Nuclear spin affected by hyperfine interaction
        qml.RX(lambda_hyperfine * params[i+1], wires=i+1)  # Electronic spin affected by hyperfine interaction

    # Magnetic field interaction with spins (Zeeman effect).
    for i in range(n_wires):
        B = B_field[i % 3]  # Apply magnetic field component to each spin
        qml.RZ(B * params[i], wires=i)  # Rotate due to magnetic field along Z-axis

    # Return the quantum state
    return qml.state()


# Function to compute the partial trace
def partial_trace(state, subsystem, full_system_size):
    """
    Computes the reduced density matrix by tracing out the qubits not in the given subsystem.
    
    Args:
        state (array): The full quantum state vector.
        subsystem (list): List of qubits to keep (the rest are traced out).
        full_system_size (int): Total number of qubits in the full system.
    
    Returns:
        array: Reduced density matrix for the selected subsystem.
    """



    rho_full = np.outer(state, state.conj())  # Full density matrix from the state vector
    dim_subsystem = 2 ** len(subsystem)  # Dimension of the subsystem Hilbert space
    dim_total = 2 ** full_system_size  # Dimension of the full system
    
    # Initialize the reduced density matrix
    rho_reduced = np.zeros((dim_subsystem, dim_subsystem), dtype=complex)
    
    # Perform partial trace: trace out qubits not in the subsystem
    subsystem_indices = [2**i for i in subsystem]
    for i in range(dim_subsystem):
        for j in range(dim_subsystem):
            for k in range(dim_total):
                if (k & sum(subsystem_indices)) == (i & sum(subsystem_indices)):
                    rho_reduced[i, j] += rho_full[k, k]

    return rho_reduced


# Function to calculate the entanglement entropy
def entropy(rho):
    """
    Calculates the von Neumann entropy, which quantifies the degree of entanglement.
    
    Args:
        rho (array): The reduced density matrix.
        
    Returns:
        float: The von Neumann entropy.
    """
    # Compute eigenvalues of the reduced density matrix
    eigvals = np.linalg.eigvalsh(rho)
    
    # Filter out very small or negative eigenvalues (set a threshold to avoid numerical issues)
    eigvals = eigvals[eigvals > 1e-10]
    
    if len(eigvals) == 0:
        return 0  # If all eigenvalues are too small or zero, return entropy of 0
    
    # Compute entropy using the filtered eigenvalues
    return -np.sum(eigvals * np.log(eigvals))



# Function to calculate the energy density shift
@qml.qnode(dev)
def energy_shift(params):
    """
    Simulates an interaction Hamiltonian and returns its expectation value.
    """
    # Apply the same operations as before
    for i in range(n_wires):
        qml.RX(params[i], wires=i)
        qml.RY(params[i + n_wires], wires=i)
        qml.RZ(params[i + 2*n_wires], wires=i)

    for i in range(0, n_wires, 2):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[i, i+1])
        qml.RX(lambda_hyperfine * params[i], wires=i)
        qml.RX(lambda_hyperfine * params[i+1], wires=i+1)

    for i in range(n_wires):
        B = B_field[i % 3]
        qml.RZ(B * params[i], wires=i)

    # Return the expectation value of the Hamiltonian (Pauli-Z terms)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0) + 0.5 * qml.PauliZ(1) + 0.2 * qml.PauliZ(2) + 0.1 * qml.PauliZ(3))

# Function to calculate the change in the stress-energy tensor
def stress_energy_tensor_change(params):
    energy_density = energy_shift(params)  # Compute energy density shift
    return energy_density  # Return energy density as change in stress-energy tensor

# Run the simulation and calculate entanglement entropy for the nuclear subsystem (now qubits 0, 2, 4, 6)
state = circuit_with_energy(params)  # Get the quantum state
subsystem = [0, 2, 4, 6]  # Define nuclear qubits
rho_reduced = partial_trace(state, subsystem, n_wires)
S_A = entropy(rho_reduced)  # Compute the entanglement entropy

# Calculate energy density shift and corresponding change in stress-energy tensor
energy_density = energy_shift(params)
delta_T_mn = stress_energy_tensor_change(params)

# Output the results
print(f"Entanglement entropy (nuclear subsystem): {S_A}")
print(f"Energy density shift: {energy_density}")
print(f"Change in stress-energy tensor: {delta_T_mn}")

full error message here:
Cell In[15], line 26
     18 kwargs_tn = {
     19     "contract": False,
     20     "local_simplify": "DCRS",
     21     "contraction_optimizer": None,
     22 }
     25 # Define a device to simulate our quantum system with 8 qubits
---> 26 dev = qml.device("default.tensor", method="tn", **kwargs_tn) 
     28 # Quantum circuit to model nuclear-electronic entanglement with hyperfine and magnetic field effects
     29 @qml.qnode(dev)
     30 def circuit_with_energy(params):

File ~\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pennylane\devices\device_constructor.py:280, in device(name, *args, **kwargs)
    274         raise qml.DeviceError(
    275             f"The {name} plugin requires PennyLane versions {required_versions}, "
    276             f"however PennyLane version {qml.version()} is installed."
    277         )
    279 # Construct the device
--> 280 dev = plugin_device_class(*args, **options)
    282 # Once the device is constructed, we set its custom expansion function if
    283 # any custom decompositions were specified.
    284 if custom_decomps is not None:

File ~\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pennylane\devices\default_tensor.py:376, in DefaultTensor.__init__(self, wires, method, c_dtype, **kwargs)
    368 def __init__(
    369     self,
    370     wires=None,
   (...)
    373     **kwargs,
    374 ) -> None:
    375     if not has_quimb:
--> 376         raise ImportError(
    377             "This feature requires quimb, a library for tensor network manipulations. "
    378             "It can be installed with:\n\npip install quimb"
    379         )  # pragma: no cover
    381     if not accepted_methods(method):
    382         raise ValueError(
    383             f"Unsupported method: {method}. Supported methods are 'mps' (Matrix Product State) and 'tn' (Exact Tensor Network)."
    384         )

ImportError: This feature requires quimb, a library for tensor network manipulations. It can be installed with:

pip install quimb
And, finally, make sure to include the versions of your packages. Specifically, show us the output of qml.about().

Could you reformat your question to include your whole code in one code snippet, as well as only the error message in the "full error message" part? As is, it is painful to try reproducing your problem.

Could you include the output of qml.about() as suggested in the error message? You seem to be using a notebook, are you sure the notebook kernel is aware of your newly installed quimb?

I entered the whole code and only the error message. Also the output of qml.about() is posted below.

please include all relevant information in the question itself

(too long for a comment)
A notebook typically use a Python "kernel" that get started when you launch the notebook session. I am not sure of the details, but you can imagine it is a Python interpreter that is run somewhere on your machine.
If you install a library after starting the notebook, it will not be aware of your install until your restart it.
Fixing your issue will depend on your setup. If the default Python of your command prompt is the one the notebook uses, you just have to restart the kernel (somewhere in the options of the notebook).
Otherwise, you will have to figure out which Python is used by the notebook (this answer might help) and install quimb and potentially other dependencies for this precise Python executable. In that case, pip install quimb and alike should be replaced by:
/the/path/of/the/Python/executable -m pip install quimb
Restarting the notebook will still be necessary.
I know some services such as Google Colab offer to host notebooks for you and let you install the library you want, if you cannot work out a solution for technical reasons.
